# Local install Eigen in CMAKE not finding target

Tags: cmake, eigen

I'm trying to build and use a local version of Eigen that I've downloaded directly from the CMake file of my project. I have those line to build it:

```
include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
        eigen
        URL ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/external/eigen-3.3.8.tar.gz
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(eigen)
set(EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR ${eigen_SOURCE_DIR})
```

But then I got errors like

```
 Target "XXX_LIBRARIES" links to target "Eigen3::Eigen" but the target was
 not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
 target, or an ALIAS target is missing?
```

I'm linhking eigen as such

```
target_link_libraries(XXX_LIBRARIES EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES Eigen3::Eigen)
```

What is surprising to me is that with this code instead everything worked fine:

```
include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
        eigen
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen.git
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(eigen)
set(EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR ${eigen_SOURCE_DIR})
```

But the only difference is that I'm downloading the library then. Why is the version with the local copy not working?

Comment: My understanding, fwiw, is that `FetchContent_Declare` always downloads the content, whereas if you already have it accessible locally you'd use something like `FindEigen.cmake` where you can tweak the path to your needs.

Comment: My goal is not to have to install it but directly load it in the Cmake file. Basically having the behavior of FetchContent_Declare without the download part. Do you know if that's possible?

Comment: @firmament Actually `Eigen` is really nice to provide a config file, so no need to write `FindEigen.cmake` module yourself, and it contains the target `Eigen3::Eigen` quite nicely.

Comment: I just realized I can use add subdirectory and use eigen instead of EIGEN::EIGEN3. Do you think that would be the correct way to use the library? I couldn't use the FindEigen without installing Eigen first

Comment: using `add_subdirectory` for a dependency is not a good practice because the dependency's CMakeLists.txt might override some of your CMake configuration and variables which leads to errors.