# How to add Eigen library to a cmake c++ project via FetchContent

Tags: c++, cmake, eigen3

Adding Eigen via

```
FetchContent_Declare(
  eigen
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen.git
  GIT_TAG        3.3.9
)

FetchContent_GetProperties(eigen)

if(NOT eigen_POPULATED)
    FetchContent_Populate(eigen)
    add_subdirectory(${eigen_SOURCE_DIR} ${eigen_BINARY_DIR})
endif()

find_package (Eigen3 3.3 REQUIRED NO_MODULE)
```

gives me the error

```
CMake Error at o/b/x64-Debug/_deps/eigen-build/Eigen3Config.cmake:20 (include):
  The file

    D:/XXX/o/b/x64-Debug/_deps/eigen-build/Eigen3Targets.cmake

  was generated by the export() command.  It may not be used as the argument
  to the include() command.  Use ALIAS targets instead to refer to targets by
  alternative names.        D:\XXX\o/b/x64-Debug/_deps/eigen-build/Eigen3Config.cmake   20
```

But downloading Eigen manually and adding it works fine

```
add_subdirectory("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/extern/eigen")
find_package (Eigen3 3.3 REQUIRED NO_MODULE)
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: If you include external project with `add_subdirectory` approach, then `find_package` is not needed.

Comment: without find package target_link_libraries throws an error

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In any order:

- Eigen only provide `ALIAS` target on master
  ref: https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/commit/cf0b5b0344a3bfcf410e95bf22289015a2daf34b#9a2aa4db38d3115ed60da621e012c0efc0172aae_671_599
- FetchContent usage could be

```
message(CHECK_START "Fetching Eigen3")
list(APPEND CMAKE_MESSAGE_INDENT "  ")

include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
  Eigen
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen.git
  GIT_TAG master
  GIT_SHALLOW TRUE
  GIT_PROGRESS TRUE)
# note: To disable eigen tests,
# you should put this code in a add_subdirectory to avoid to change
# BUILD_TESTING for your own project too since variables are directory
# scoped
set(BUILD_TESTING OFF)
set(EIGEN_BUILD_TESTING OFF)
set(EIGEN_MPL2_ONLY ON)
set(EIGEN_BUILD_PKGCONFIG OFF)
set(EIGEN_BUILD_DOC OFF)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(Eigen)

list(POP_BACK CMAKE_MESSAGE_INDENT)
message(CHECK_PASS "fetched")
...
target_link_libraries(YourTarget PRIVATE Eigen3::Eigen)
```

- For `find_package()` and `FetchContent()/add_subdirectory()` please see
  https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/17735 
  EDIT: now you can also use `FIND_PACKAGE_ARGS NAMES Eigen3` in `Fetchcontent_Declare()`
  ref: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FetchContent.html#integrating-with-find-package

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked perfectly :)

Comment: This only worked correctly for me when using `target_link_libraries(YourTarget PRIVATE eigen)` edit: fetching `GIT_TAG 3.3.9` from eigen repo

Comment: What does `set( OFF)` do?

Comment: @AlecJacobson wrong copy/paste sorry...

Answer (score 3):

Alright i gave up on FetchContent, i also tried this [Local install Eigen in CMAKE not finding target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65080150/local-install-eigen-in-cmake-not-finding-target) but this didn't work for me either.

I use ExternalProject now (https://github.com/qulacs/qulacs/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt) for fetching and linking eigen

```
include(ExternalProject)

set(EIGEN_BUILD_DIR   ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/eigen)
set(EIGEN_INSTALL_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/eigen3)
set(EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIR ${EIGEN_INSTALL_DIR})

ExternalProject_Add(
    eigen
    URL https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/archive/3.3.7/eigen-3.3.7.tar.gz
    PREFIX ${EIGEN_BUILD_DIR}
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
    BUILD_COMMAND ""
    INSTALL_COMMAND
      ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory ${EIGEN_BUILD_DIR}/src/eigen/Eigen ${EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIR}/Eigen 
      && ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory ${EIGEN_BUILD_DIR}/src/eigen/unsupported ${EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIR}/unsupported
    TEST_COMMAND ""
)
include_directories(SYSTEM ${EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

Additionally add_dependencies has to be used

```
add_executable(test1 "test1.cpp")
add_dependencies(test1 eigen)
```

Answer (score 2):

Fetchcontent is great, but it has the unwanted side-effect that your workspace becomes cluttered by all targets of your dependency. If you don't like this then `ExternalProject_Add` seems to be a reasonable solution. In your case the following should work:

```
include(ExternalProject)

set(EIGEN_INSTALL_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/eigen-install/")

ExternalProject_Add(
    eigen
    URL  https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/archive/3.4.0/eigen-3.4.0.tar.gz
    SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/eigen-src"
    BINARY_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/eigen-build"
    INSTALL_DIR "${EIGEN_INSTALL_DIR}"
    CMAKE_ARGS
    -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=<INSTALL_DIR>
    -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
)

file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${EIGEN_INSTALL_DIR}/include)  # avoid race condition

add_library(eigenlib INTERFACE IMPORTED GLOBAL)
add_dependencies(eigenlib eigen)
target_compile_features(eigenlib INTERFACE cxx_std_14)

set_target_properties(eigenlib PROPERTIES
  INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${EIGEN_INSTALL_DIR}/include/eigen3
)
```

Note that the dependecy is linked to an interface library `eigenlib` that you can subsequenly link to your own targets as follows:

```
add_library(linalg INTERFACE)
target_include_directories(linalg
    INTERFACE 
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}>
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>)

target_link_libraries(linalg INTERFACE eigenlib)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to expand on @Mizux's answer.

In their comment, there is a `set( OFF)` statement that does nothing. Also, to remove a CMake warning, you might need to do:

```
include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
  Eigen
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen.git
  GIT_TAG master
  GIT_SHALLOW TRUE
  GIT_PROGRESS TRUE)
set(CMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP0077 NEW)
set(EIGEN_BUILD_DOC OFF)
set(EIGEN_BUILD_PKGCONFIG OFF)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(Eigen)
```

This removes the warning for [this policy change.](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/policy/CMP0077.html)

Comment: So, why is all that necessary, e.g., why would this work?:

> FetchContent_Declare(eigen URL https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/archive/3.4.0/eigen-3.4.0.tar)
> FetchContent_MakeAvailable(eigen)

What are the cons here?