# Accessing external libraries loaded with FetchContent located in subdirectories in the main CMakeLists.txt

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, fetchcontent

I have the following directory structure for my app. The libraries in the `external` directory all use `fetchcontent` command.

```
myapp
│
│ CMakeLists.txt
│
├───data
│ data.csv
│
├───external
│ ├───csv-parser
│ │ CMakeLists.txt
│ │
│ ├───eigen
│ │ CMakeLists.txt
│ │
│ └───fmt
│ CMakeLists.txt
│
├───include
│ myapp.h
│
├───out
│ └───build
│
├───src
│ main.cpp
│
└───tests
```

The `CMakeLists.txt` in the `csv-parser` folder is as follows.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
project(libcsvparser VERSION 1.0.0)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

include(FetchContent)
include(CMakePrintHelpers)

FetchContent_Declare(csv_parser
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/ben-strasser/fast-cpp-csv-parser.git)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(csv_parser)
cmake_print_variables(csv_parser_SOURCE_DIR csv_parser_BINARY_DIR)
```

The `CMakeLists.txt` in the `fmt` folder is as follows.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
project(libfmt VERSION 1.0.0)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

include(FetchContent)
include(CMakePrintHelpers)

FetchContent_Declare(fmt GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(fmt)
cmake_print_variables(fmt_SOURCE_DIR fmt_BINARY_DIR)
```

The `CMakeLists.txt` in the `eigen` folder is as follows.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
project(libeigen VERSION 1.0.0)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

include(FetchContent)
include(CMakePrintHelpers)

FetchContent_Declare(eigen
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen.git)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(eigen)
cmake_print_variables(eigen_SOURCE_DIR eigen_BINARY_DIR)
```

For all the external libraries, I get the correct `???_SOURCE_DIR` and `???_BINARY_DIR` printed during the build.

The main `CMakeLists.txt` is as follows.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
project(myapp VERSION 1.0.0)

include(FetchContent)
include(CMakePrintHelpers)

cmake_print_variables(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

add_subdirectory(external/csv-parser)
add_subdirectory(external/eigen)
add_subdirectory(external/fmt)

cmake_print_variables(csv_parser_SOURCE_DIR)
cmake_print_variables(eigen_SOURCE_DIR)
cmake_print_variables(fmt_SOURCE_DIR)

add_executable(myapp)
target_sources(myapp PRIVATE src/main.cpp)
target_include_directories(myapp PUBLIC include)
target_include_directories(myapp PUBLIC csv_parser_SOURCE_DIR)
target_include_directories(myapp PUBLIC eigen_SOURCE_DIR)
target_include_directories(myapp PUBLIC fmt_SOURCE_DIR)
```

I am having trouble accessing the external libraries in the main `CMakeLists.txt` and during its build the following commands will print empty as if the `add_subdirectory` did not work correctly.:

```
csv_parser_SOURCE_DIR=""
eigen_SOURCE_DIR=""
fmt_SOURCE_DIR=""
```

Because of this my Visual Studio does not recognize where the following include files are and I can't build the `myapp` target.

```
#include "Eigen/Dense"
#include "fmt/core.h"
#include <csv.h>
```

Answer (score 1):

The most simplest way is to set the variable, {project}_SROUCE_DIR, to PARENT_SCOPE.
For example, you can add below code in your CMakeLists.txt of the fmt directory.

```
set(fmt_SOURCE_DIR ${fmt_SOURCE_DIR} PARENT_SCOPE)
```

The reason why main CMakeLists could not access that variable is the variable scope related problem.

{project}_SOURCE_DIR variable is valid while configuring {project} subdirectory.

Comment: Thanks but I still get the error for the `#include` files, e.g. `cannot open source file "Eigen/Dense"`. I feel like there should be another way to access fetchcontent libraries in the main CMakeLists.txt.

Answer (score 1):

If a subproject follows the *target-oriented* style ("modern CMake"), then one rarely need to know its source or binary directory: for consume the subproject in the `CMakeLists.txt` you could just **link** with the **target(s)** created by the subproject.

E.g. in case of Eigen you could write

```
target_link_libraries(myapp PUBLIC Eigen3::Eigen)
```

([How to add Eigen library to a cmake c++ project via FetchContent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65860094/how-to-add-eigen-library-to-a-cmake-c-project-via-fetchcontent)).

If a subproject doesn't follow the target-oriented style, and instead of `target_include_directories` uses `include_directories`, then you could "fix" that problem by adding missing properties in the same `CMakeLists.txt` where FetchContent for that project is called. So the rest of your code could use `target_link_libraries` as in the previous case.

E.g. [csv-parser](https://github.com/ben-strasser/fast-cpp-csv-parser) contains a single header and doesn't provide `CMakeLists.txt`. You may create an IMPORTED target which represents a header-only library:

```
# in csv-parser/CMakeLists.txt
add_library(csv_parser INTERFACE)
target_include_directories(csv_parser INTERFACE ${csv_parser_SOURCE_DIR})
```

and link with that target in outer code:

```
# in top-level CMakeLists.txt
target_link_libraries(app PUBLIC csv_parser)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for such a nice explanation. `Eigen` worked nicely. For `csv_parser`, I had to add `add_library(csv_parser::csv_parser ALIAS csv_parser)` and `target_link_libraries(myapp PUBLIC csv_parser::csv_parser)` in their `CMakeLists.txt`s in order to get it to work. Could you shed light on why I needed this? It did not build without the `ALIAS`.

Comment: Linking with the INTERFACE library (`csv_parser` in my example) should be sufficient. Creating an ALIAS for it is optional.

Comment: Thank you very much. You are right. It worked.